# Fire callback when selection was made with select2 4.0, and retrieve the value of last selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using the latest version of Select2 (4.0), and can't find out how to fire an event when a selection was made, AND retrieve the last selected value(when working with select boxes where multiple selections is possible).

In older versions of Select2, if I remember correctly, the "onchange" event of the select to which the plugin was attached fired when a selection was made, this doesn't work at the momment.

I've managed to fire a javascript function when the select boxes selection changes, but can't figure out the last selected id yet. Here's how I did it:

```
jQuery("#select2_holder").on("change", function(e) { 
        console.log(arguments);
});
```

I've also tried logging the arguments, but I can't find the desired information there either.

I've read through the documentation on the official website, but I can't find anything about callback functions in it.

Is there someone here who could point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 provides the `select2:select` event which is triggered any time a new value is selected. For a single select, this is equivalent to `change` with some extra metadata included.

You can get the selected data object using `evt.data` where `evt` is the first argument passed into the event handler.

```
jQuery("#select2_holder").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.data);
});
```

You can find a live example of the events [in the Select2 examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#events).

---

> In older versions of Select2, if I remember correctly, the "onchange" event of the select to which the plugin was attached fired when a selection was made, this doesn't work at the momment.

This is correct, in Select2 3.x we used to modify the standard `change` event and put a few extra attributes on it. Since this was (unfortunately) never consistent, and it caused problems when people wanted to trigger `change` manually, we are not modifying the standard `change` event in Select2 4.0.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

Prev example is good, but 1 mistake :
need use `select2:selecting` instead of `select2:select`

So we have

```
jQuery("#select2_holder").on("select2:selecting", function (evt) {
  console.log(evt);
});
```