# Cannot retrieve the value to be selected on select2:selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using **Select2 4.0.3** with single selection.

I am trying to get the value to be selected (the one that the user select and will be assigned) before the change event is triggered.

This is code I am using to hook the event and what I tested:

```
$('#mycombo').on("select2:selecting", function (evt) {

  var $this = $(this);

  console.log($this.val()); // This return the current value
  console.log(evt.data);    // This return unassigned
  console.log(evt.params);  // This return unassigned
  console.log(evt.args);    // This return unassigned
  console.log(evt.object);  // This return unassigned      
})
```

I also tried the example here [Fire callback when selection was made with select2 4.0, and retrieve the value of last selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376121/fire-callback-when-selection-was-made-with-select2-4-0-and-retrieve-the-value-o) but it look like the select and change events are triggered simultaneously.

I am lost and any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have that information that is in params, try for example with this

```
$('#mycombo').on("select2:selecting", function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.params.args.data);  // this returns the object of 
})
```

and then in data you can do something like .text or .id and you have the text of the option or the value respectively.

```
evt.params.args.data.text
```

Comment: here is a working example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egmraE?editors=1010